# Hapi.js - Unable to serve static file in SPA

Tags: node.js, static-files, hapi.js

I have just attempted to make a SPA but i am not able to resolve index.html dependencies (like including associated css, js files). All the js and css file are not able to load into browser and show `404` error in dev console.

```
/root
|
|__public
|      └── spa
|          ├── controllers
|          ├── css
|          ├── html
|          ├── js-self
|          ├── js-vendor
|          └── services
|_____________ index.html
```

**Route declaration**

```
var assets = function(){
    return {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory :{
                path : 'public',
                index: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Order of all routes**

```
  info: ================Registered routes=============
info: Route:    GET /employee
info: Route:    POST    /employee
info: Route:    PUT /employee
info: Route:    DELETE  /employee
info: Route:    POST    /signin
info: Route:    POST    /signup
info: Route:    POST    /signout
info: Route:    GET /{param*}
info: Route:    GET /
info: =============================================
```

**Html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0058)http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/#contact -->
<html lang="en" ng-app="ibs">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <script src="./public/spa/js-vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/spa/js-vendor/angular-1.3.14.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/spa/js-vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/spa/app.js"></script>
    <link href="./public/spa/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./public/spa/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./public/spa/css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .appbkg {
          background: #303F9F
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="appbkg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="./Starter Template for Bootstrap_files/Starter Template for Bootstrap.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" ng-view>
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="./public/spa/js-vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Where is hapi's main file located?

Comment: immediately under root.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example? It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Please visit the link and get access to the project. 
You will find routes folder under src. Routes folder has file `web_route.js'. This file contains route for web app. You will find the mentioned function in
 this file. main.js file in Routes folder acts as manager which takes in all the routes in every file under routes folder. and this main file is fed into server.route().



https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0lextxzzfslbze/tsms%28copy%29.tar.gz?dl=0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made it work with this little edit:

```
var assets = function(){
return {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory :{
            path : './',
            index: false
        }
    }
}
}
```

the `./` path is actually relative to where you are when you run `node app.js`.

So make sure you are in the root folder when you run it. As `node ../app.js` doesn't work !!

Since that's not very clean, **avoid** using paths that way and stick to using `path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/folder')` with __dirname as a reference. 
Here is a cleaner solution for you

```
var assets = function(){
return {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory :{
            path : path.join(__dirname, '../..'),
            index: false
        }
    }
}
}
```

### Note [from node's docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

`__dirname` is :

> The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.